# Почему надо 2 раза писать va_arg

Tags: c

Здравствуйте! Написал лабу по функции с переменным числом параметров. Первый параметр - размерность массива, второй - указатель на массив.

Но не могу понять, почему для того чтобы перейти к след. элементу необходимо два раза писать переход к следующему элементу?

```
a=va_arg(arg1,int);
a=va_arg(arg1,int);
```

и

```
n=va_arg(arg2,double*);
n=va_arg(arg2,double*);
```

В гугле везде примеры с 1 параметром -_-
А как сделать чтобы 2 раза не писать?(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

float getsum(int a,double *n,...) { //
    int i;      
    double s=0;
    va_list arg1; 
    va_list arg2;
    va_start(arg1,a);
    va_start(arg2,n);    

    printf("\nas = %d",a);
    printf("\nns = %lf\n",n[0]);

    while (1) {     
        for(i=0;i<a;i++) s+=n[i];

        a=va_arg(arg1,int);
        a=va_arg(arg1,int);
        if(a==0) break;
        printf("\na1 = %d",a);
        n=va_arg(arg2,double*);
        n=va_arg(arg2,double*);
        printf("\nn1 = %lf\n",n[0]);    
    }


    va_end(arg1);        
    va_end(arg2);  
    return s;
}


void main() {   
    double d[2]={5.5,2.2}; 
    double f[4]={1.1,2.1,1.3,4.1}; 
    double g[1]={3.7}; 


    double s;
    s = getsum(2,d,4,f,1,g,0);
    printf("\nSumma vseh chisel massivov = %lf",s);
    getch();
}
```

---

Всё, разобрался! Внизу - "правильная" функция без повторов

```
float getsum(int a,double n,...) { 
    int i;  
    double s=0; 
    va_list args; 
    va_start(args,a); 
    va_start(args,n);   
    while (1) { 
        for(i=0;i<a;i++) 
            s+=n[i]; 
        a=va_arg(args,int); 
        if(a==0) 
            break; 
        n=va_arg(args,double); 
    } 
    va_end(args); 
    return s; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что `va_list arg1` в действительности представляет не один аргумент, а все. Поэтому корректнее переменную следует назвать `args`. Аргументы выбираются последовательно, как вы уже догадались.

Comment: А как сделать чтобы 2 раза не писать?(

Answer (score 1):

Два раза va_start писать **не надо**, и va_arg надо писать *один* раз для каждого аргумента, *которого* **нет** *в списке*.

Например

```
void
targs (int n, char *s, ...)
{
  int  i = n;
  char *p = s;
  va_list args;
  va_start (args, s);

  while (1) {
    printf ("i = %d s = %s\n",i,p);
    if (!(i = va_arg(args,int)))
      break;
    p = va_arg(args, char *);
  }
  va_end(args);

}

main ()
{
  targs(1,"one",2,"two",3,"three",0);
}
```

Т.е. Вашу функцию можно написать так

```
double 
getsum (int n, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  va_start (args, n);

  double s = 0.0, *arr;
  int    sz = n, i;

  while (sz)  {
    arr = va_arg(args, double *);
    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++) s += arr[i];
    sz = va_arg(args, int);
  }
  va_end(args);
  return s;
}
```

Один раз va_start и по одному разу va_arg для размера и адреса массива.